# How do I assign values to variables in a struct that is used within another struct in swift?

Tags: swift, struct

I am trying to learn Swift and just found out about structs. I have this code:

```
struct Time {
  var hour: Int
  var minute: Int
}

struct Class {
  var title: String //name of class
  var room: Int //room number
  var building: String
  var teacher: String //name of teacher
  var block: Character
  var startTime: Time
  var endTime: Time
}

var math = Class(title: "Math", room: 801, building: "Math Building", teacher: "Ms. Teacher", block: 'G', startTime: Time, endTime: Time)
```

How do I assign values to the hour and minute variables this way or is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `startTime: Time(hour: 0, minute: 0), endTime: Time(hour: 7, minute: 7)`?

Comment: Yes, Is that the syntax?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. I didn't realize it was that simple

Comment: You might want to call your struct a `Course` or something. `struct Class` will be very confusing, people will think it's a dummy/sample `class` called "Class"

Comment: It would be good practice to pick clearer names for your properties, so you wouldn't need the comments: e.g. `teacherName`, `roomNumber`, `className`

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the (child) structure and then pass it to the constructor.

```swift
let startTime = Time(hour: 0, minute: 0)
let endTime = Time(hour: 12, minute: 60)
let math = Class(title: "Math", 
                 room: 801, 
                 building: "Math Building", 
                 teacher: "Ms. Teacher", 
                 block: "G", 
                 startTime: startTime, 
                 endTime: endTime)
```

Alternatively, you can also initialize at the time we are passing it as a parameter to make it concise

```swift
let math = Class(title: "Math", 
                 room: 801, 
                 building: "Math Building", 
                 teacher: "Ms. Teacher", 
                 block: "G", 
                 startTime: Time(hour: 0, minute: 0), 
                 endTime: Time(hour: 12, minute: 60))
```